# Concatenation of two string field in db context in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I want to perform the following query in dbcontext(Entity framework 4.1)
Please Help .

Select empcode+'-'+Empname as empName from tblemployee

Answer (score 0):

```
from employee in context.Employees
select new { empName = employee.empcode + employee.Empname }
```